# Using a Generic Switching Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, power

I have a generic 5V 10A switching power supply with screw terminals, that looks kind-of like this:

[image: Power supply]

Is it safe to use the output from here to drive the Pi by cutting a USB cable and connecting the power wires to the terminals?  I am already using this power supply to power a set of LED lights (similar to [these](http://www.adafruit.com/products/306)) and I want to avoid needing an extra power supply just for the RPi if I can help it.

Is there anything in particular that I need to be careful about when doing this, other than accidentally crossing the wires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used a 12v version of this and then used a linear regulator to drop it down to 5v.

It worked fine for driving the Pi but because it is a switched mode power supply the output is quite "noisy" and even putting it through the linear regulator I still had the noise. I was using the Pi to switch camera outputs and the resulting picture had lots of lines of interference on it.

Comment: I'm curious about the noise you mention.  My DC power supply experience is limited and I was having a tough time assessing why my 5v switch mode PS seemed to be affecting my 3D printer connected to my RP3.  Any time I'd send a Gcode command to the Arduino (running Marlin), the USB connection would reset and I'd have to restart the RP for it to properly connect again.  I was trying to filter out irregular voltage, but I ended up creating another problem, it would seem.

Comment: The average voltage will be fine but the noise I was seeing was related to the switching frequency of the power supply (say 60kHz). Because it had such a fast edge to it, my grounding/filtering wasn't adequate and because it wasn't synchronized to the video camera I got the interference.For the digital case you have it might be more down to the ability of the power supply to supply the necessary current under demand.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of overkill, but as long as it is 5v it should work.  And skip the USB hack.  Power through the GPIO connections.

See:  [Safest way to power a hungry Wifi adapter and the Pi from a single 5V source](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15261/safest-way-to-power-a-hungry-wifi-adapter-and-the-pi-from-a-single-5v-source?rq=1)

and

[Suitable power supply for DC power through GPIO](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7723/suitable-power-supply-for-dc-power-through-gpio?rq=1)

Edit:  The USB hack will work.  I just think the GPIO pins are easier to connect to.